# UniformGrid Layout

Tags: c#, wpf, uniformgrid

I know that Uniform grid does not support row span, but its somehow possible by overriding a method from what i read on Google, but i could really use an example how can i do this. What i want to achieve is a layout similar to this:

```
 ----------
|  1  | 2  |
 ----------
|    3     |
 ----------
```

So basically i want the third children to be spanned over 2 columns. I could use a grid but sadly i don't know any method how can i do this because all the children's are created dynamically and i cannot specify in witch cell the child will be put.

Comment: If you read that in google then you should have posted the link. But you didn't read it in google because it isn't possible: uniform means uniform. OTOH, google does tell you how to set the row and column of an item in a Grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you'd be better off using a `Grid` control. Although you say that you *cannot specify in which cell the child will be put*, I would try to fix *that* problem, rather than to create a new control. If you can fix that issue, then this might help you.

To populate a particular row in code, you can use the `Grid.SetRow` method and to populate a particular column, you can use the `Grid.SetColumn` method:

```
Grid.SetRow(rectangle, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(rectangle, 1);
```

Likewise, to set a row span, you can use the `Grid.SetRowSpan` method and to set a column span, you can use the `Grid.SetColumnSpan` method:

```
Grid.SetRowSpan(rectangle, 2);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(rectangle, 2);
```

Please see the [`Grid.SetRow` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.setrow.aspx), [`Grid.SetRowSpan` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.setrowspan.aspx) , [`Grid.SetColumn` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.setcolumn.aspx) and [`Grid.SetColumnSpan` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.setcolumnspan.aspx) pages on MSDN for a full example on this.

Comment: The problem is that i cannot control the docs that are generated, i just have to make a style and display them, with the uniform grid works perfectly as i want except for the 3rd docs that comes and i want to display it on the full row ( like you can do with column span )

Comment: If you found an article that shows you how to add span properties to your `UniformGrid`, then go with that... I've not seen one and can't see how it would work without re-writing the internal `ItemsPanel` which is not trivial.